# How to get bundle's child product ids

Tags: magento-1.9

By using the following code 
[Get Bundle product ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255962/magento-get-a-list-of-bundled-product-ids-from-a-product-id)

```
$productIDs = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getChildrenIds($product->getId(), false)

Mage::log($productIDs);
```

using above retrive multi-dimensional array..

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [21] => 21
        [25] => 25
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [28] => 28
    )
)
```

in my case i have a bundle with three product... i just need product ids(21, 25 and 28) 
i try a lot but unable figure out. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I really need help!!

Comment: try this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/316629/82670

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the below code ,

```
         $id = 10;//bundled product id
         $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($id);
         $collection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product), $product);

         $itemIds = array();

         foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $itemIds[] = $item->getId();
           // echo "<pre>";
           // print_r($item->getData());
           // echo "</pre>";
         }
         var_dump($itemIds);
```

Comment: Thanks @saravanavelu `Array
(
    [0] => 21
    [1] => 28
    [2] => 25
)`   now get array value like this... still i need only array value's 21- 28 and 25...by using these value i need to calculate some value..  please have a look

Comment: Done getting value... here is a code `foreach ($itemIds as $key=>$item){               $bundleIds = $itemIds[$keys[$i]];` $i++;

Comment: Very nice code, Can we get only a list of default options of bundle items to a bundle product?