# How to load bundle child product by parent product ID?

Tags: magento2, product, bundled-product, bundle

I want to load bundle child products from bundle product parent id in Magento 2.

anyone know how can we achieve this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the type instance in your bundle product, then get the children IDs, as below.

```
$typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
$requiredChildrenIds = $typeInstance->getChildrenIds($product->getId(), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this code**

```
    protected $productdata;
    
    
    public function __construct(
        ............................................
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productdata,
        ............................................
    ) {
        ............................................
        $this->productdata = $productdata;
        ............................................
    }
.......................................................................

    public function getBundleProudct(){
    
        //$prd is the current product collection or you add your product object
    
        if ($prd->getTypeId() == 'bundle') {
    
            $typeInstance = $prd->getTypeInstance();
            $requiredChildrenIds = $typeInstance->getChildrenIds($prd->getId(), false);
            //print_r($requiredChildrenIds);

            foreach ($requiredChildrenIds as $Childrenkey => $Childrenvalue) {
                foreach ($Childrenvalue as $key => $value) {
                    //print_r($value);
                    $child = $this->productdata->create()->load($value);
                    print_r($child->getName());
                    echo "<br/>";
                }

            }
    }
```

***I Hope This Helps You***